# Dynamic content bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using `Bootstrap popover`. Everything works just fine.
I am displaying `div` on popover. Here I [created js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rK34t/5/). Now how do I replace `title` and `contents`? Thanks

EDIT: I am also not able to click on `Show details` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you cant click the show details button is due to your use of hover, you should either revert to using click or set a delay before the hover effect disappears:

```
$('#popover').popover({
    delay: { show: 100, hide: 500 }
});
```

I would suggest creating a separate popover link for each item you want to display, see [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rK34t/9/) for an example. Another option would be to use jquery to change the text of the div for each click of a popover link.

Comment: I am going to use your method. Because Its clean. Now I am facing one more problem. Can you please take look? `alert()` function is not working in `popover` windows. Here is [my jsfiddlde](http://jsfiddle.net/4FujN/2/). Thanks

Comment: Glad to have solved your problem. Sorry but I have no experience with raty so I can't help you with that, maybe simplify it, do the buttons work? Might be that you can't respond to click events from a popover (in which case a modal box might be better). Also please mark as answered if I answered your question

Comment: Seems to be an problem with dynamic content, when you're binding raty the popovers don't exist so you need to bind when they do. See updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FujN/6/)